# Google App Engine: Using different handlers depending on user role

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb, webapp2

My webapp has two user 'roles': '*Designer*' and '*Programmer*'.

The app's front page is handled by:

```
class Front(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        role = self.get_user_role() #somehow gets the current user role.
        if role == 'Designer':
            #redirect to DesignerFront(BaseHandler)
        elif role == 'Programmer':
            #redirect to ProgrammerFront(BaseHandler)

class DesignerFront(BaseHandler):
    # do something

class ProgrammerFront(BaseHandler):
    # do something
```

I currently have one handler which handles queries for both roles, and I think this might be unnecessarily expensive.

Is it possible to forward a process to a different handler like the example above? Additionally, is this recommended? Perhaps there is a better way to do this that I am unaware of.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: You can call the other handlers directly and return their results rather than doing a redirect.

Comment: See additions to the answer above

Answer (score 0):

You can return a HTTP 307 redirect to the DesignerFront or ProgrammerFront URLs.

This is acceptable.  You generally don't want to constantly have redirects, since it slows down performance (a user would have to request the Front page, get redirected, then go to the appropriate page).  If the user experiences this only once while visiting your site, it's not such a bit deal.

Comment: Thanks for answering, dragonx. I think there is a preference to not actually do a URL redirect here. I don't want the front page to be `/designer-front` or `/programmer-front`. I just want it to be `/`. This is why I think it's best to call another handler (example: `DesignerFront(BaseHandler)` or `ProgrammerFront(BaseHandler)`) to render the front page once the role is determined by `Front(BaseHandler)`. Unless, there is a better, conventional way to handle a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.  You can call the handlers directly and in many cases this will be preferable to doing a redirect.

The biggest single reason will be to simplify your security model.  If you redirect based on the users role then you have to do the security check again in the user specific handler as anyone can guess the handler urls.  By calling the handler directly you have already performed the check and only have to perform and maintain it in one place.

You can do it something like the following

```
class Front(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        role = self.get_user_role() #somehow gets the current user role.

        if role == 'Designer':

            dh = DesignerFront(self.request,self.response)
            dh.get()

        elif role == 'Programmer':

            #redirect to ProgrammerFront(BaseHandler)
```

I don't use webapp(2) for any of my projects, I found the routes don't suit open ended URL schemes as well as some other URL mapping tools/libs (at least for my projects).

In our larger projects the users view is made up of many pieces that depend on the context (where they are), their role (who they are) etc... so the top level URL just provides the container view, and then we lookup based on (request.type, context, user, view) appropriate components to fill in the various parts of the page, so top level view defines the calling context, and all permissions, then looks up/fetchs the various found components. (I won't go into that detail here as it will probably distract you and introduce more unfamiliar frameworks).

Comment: Thanks for answering, Tim. How does the code for something like this look like? I'm am a beginner at python and GAE.